# Read and return a file content in plain asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a simple service so that other applications can poll a url, for instance

```
http://IP/serverstatus.aspx
```

And get status in a single line, no "html". But how do I output that, Im currently reading a file in the file's c# code just fine, and its the contents on this file that is going to be outputted.

Comment: Is your question related to [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the ContentType
- Clear the Response (I think this is optional)
- Write to the Response
- Make sure your ASPX-file is empty

Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("yourfile.txt"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Response header to plain text

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Response.Write("hello world");
Response.End();
```